# numpy: ndarray index with repeated values

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Consider I have an array:

```
arr2 = np.array([10., 10., 10.,  10.,  10.,  10., 10., 10., 10., 10.])
```

and an index with repeated values:

```
idx = np.array([3,3,3,4,4,5])
```

If I do so:

```
arr2[idx] -=1
```

then I got this:

```
array([10., 10., 10.,  9.,  9.,  9., 10., 10., 10., 10.])
```

But I want to subtract by each value in index, taking into account the repetitions! How to get this?

```
array([10., 10., 10.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 10., 10., 10.])
```

Comment: `for i in idx: arr2[i] -= 1`

Comment: `np.add.at` handkes the duplicates as you want

Comment: @hpaulj Thanx, that it!